# Java GUI setup with JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So I'm working on a GUI for a project, and I would like to set it up as follows:

- Two JTables(one on BorderLayout.WEST, the other on BorderLayout.EAST)
- Two JComboBox's that sit above the JTables
- One Panel that sits between the JTables(BorderLayout.CENTER)

Can someone help me with this? I'm having trouble with the spacing between the components.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: See [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556) for an example (in the form of an MCVE)..

Answer (score 1):

Read the `BorderLayout` API. You can specify the vertical and horizontal gap between the various areas of the BorderLayout. So reset the layout manager of the frame with a BorderLayout that uses your desired gaps:

```
BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout(...);
frame.setLayout( layout );
frame.add(new JScrollPane(table1), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
frame.add(new JScrollPane(table2), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

Also, you can create sub panels and use different layout managers on each panel to get your desired effect.

If you need more help then post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.